# How can I bind between differents user controls?

Tags: c#, database, winforms, model-view-controller, data-binding

I'm creating a database system, and I'm creating my program right now which connects to database.

I'm working with a table called Parts. In the program I've created two user controls, one of them is the list view of all the parts and the another one is the selected details. (Below are the images)

I'm looking for the way to bind the data between these user controls. I mean the user has selected a row, and the details view must show all the data about the selected item.

I'm not sure, but I really wanted to do the good things. I guess I should use some design patterns like MVC. I really don't know about it.

Thanks a lot.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using a `dataGridView`. You could use the [`RowEnter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowenter.aspx) event that will be fired when a row gets focus and load the details of the current part by retrieving its ID.

```
private void dataGridView_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    String partId = dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[PartID].Value.ToString();
    // Load details with partId
    // ...
}
```